# How do I use filter_map() rather then filter() combined with map() without performance decreasing?

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator

I would like to use `filter_map()` instead of `unwrap()` in the `map()` and `filter()` but I see a performance decrease when doing this. How do I write the code using `filter_map()` without losing performance? Why is there a loss of performance in the first place?

**src/lib.rs**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub enum Kind {
    Square(Square),
    Circle(Circle),
}

#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Circle {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
    c: u32,
    d: u32,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Square {
    a: u32,
    b: Option<u32>,
    c: Option<u32>,
    d: Option<u32>,
    e: Option<u32>,
}

impl Kind {
    pub fn get_circle(&self) -> Option<&Circle> {
        if let Kind::Circle(b) = self {
            return Some(b);
        }
        None
    }
}
```

**benches/test.rs**

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr};
    use test::Bencher;
    use testing::Circle;
    use testing::Kind;
    use testing::Square;

    fn get_bencher() -> HashMap<SocketAddr, Kind> {
        let mut question = HashMap::new();
        let square: Square = Default::default();
        question.insert(
            SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 0),
            Kind::Square(square),
        );

        let circle: Circle = Default::default();
        for n in 1..=10000 {
            let socket = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), n);
            question.insert(socket, Kind::Circle(circle));
        }
        question
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bencher01(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let question = get_bencher();

        b.iter(|| {
            question
                .iter()
                .map(|a| (a.0, a.1.get_circle()))
                .filter_map(|(&a, b)| Some((a, b?)))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bencher02(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let question = get_bencher();

        b.iter(|| {
            question
                .iter()
                .map(|a| (a.0, a.1.get_circle()))
                .filter(|c| c.1.is_some())
                .map(|d| (*d.0, d.1.unwrap()))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bencher03(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let question = get_bencher();

        b.iter(|| {
            question
                .iter()
                .filter_map(|a| Some((*a.0, a.1.get_circle()?)))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
    }
}
```

Run these tests using Rust nightly and `cargo bench` which forces release mode.

**output**

```
running 3 tests
test tests::bencher01 ... bench:     201,978 ns/iter (+/- 12,787)
test tests::bencher02 ... bench:      89,004 ns/iter (+/- 6,204)
test tests::bencher03 ... bench:     238,569 ns/iter (+/- 6,004)
```

I'm using `rustc 1.44.0-nightly (6dee5f112 2020-04-06)` on `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz Linux #### 5.6.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon, 13 Apr 2020 12:21:19 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What does your profiler say is the slow part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that in your `flat_map` implementations, you copy the `SocketAddr` before you check whether the shape is a circle, so you waste time copying and discarding it when the shape is not a circle. See:

```
#[bench]
fn bencher04(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let question = get_bencher();

    b.iter(|| {
        question
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|a| {
                let c = a.1.get_circle()?;
                Some((*a.0, c))
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    })
}
```

Which gives me:

```
running 4 tests
test tests::bencher01 ... bench:     339,720 ns/iter (+/- 23,464)
test tests::bencher02 ... bench:     329,727 ns/iter (+/- 12,212)
test tests::bencher03 ... bench:     335,785 ns/iter (+/- 16,195)
test tests::bencher04 ... bench:     327,622 ns/iter (+/- 20,807)
```

Note: The difference is lower for me than for you because I'm running on a 32-bits platform on which copying the `SocketAddr` is much faster.

---

On 64-bits platforms, `bencher04` does not perform as well. Looking at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/F9_62Y), `bencher04` appears very similar to `bencher02` but it does move more data around for some reason.

However:

```
#[bench]
fn bencher05(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let question = get_bencher();

    b.iter(|| {
        question
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|a| {
                a.1.get_circle().map (|c| (*a.0, c))
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
    }
```

Comes closer in performance:

```
running 5 tests
test tests::bencher01 ... bench:     219,381 ns/iter (+/- 10,186)
test tests::bencher02 ... bench:     148,273 ns/iter (+/- 3,068)
test tests::bencher03 ... bench:     244,614 ns/iter (+/- 3,057)
test tests::bencher04 ... bench:     209,905 ns/iter (+/- 7,509)
test tests::bencher05 ... bench:     167,143 ns/iter (+/- 5,029)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I ran the code that you posted on my system and I'm still seeing the performance drop:

running 4 tests
test tests::bencher01 ... bench:     208,874 ns/iter (+/- 35,134)
test tests::bencher02 ... bench:      94,463 ns/iter (+/- 39,286)
test tests::bencher03 ... bench:     259,229 ns/iter (+/- 52,471)
test tests::bencher04 ... bench:     213,174 ns/iter (+/- 46,104)

Comment: Your edit created around the same performance as the unwrap(), accepted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your `05` is drastically slower than your `04` for me (`90,690 ns/iter (+/- 8,639)` vs `169,073 ns/iter (+/- 32,725)`). In fact, `05` is the slowest implementation of all of them by almost 50%.

Comment: I had the following results: test tests::bencher01 ... bench:     198,970 ns/iter (+/- 8,671)
test tests::bencher02 ... bench:      87,531 ns/iter (+/- 2,857)
test tests::bencher03 ... bench:     237,512 ns/iter (+/- 9,739)
test tests::bencher04 ... bench:     198,910 ns/iter (+/- 6,194)
test tests::bencher05 ... bench:     146,388 ns/iter (+/- 13,196)